# unable to hide logout button after signout using ng-show in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the logout button like this:

```
<li class="dropdown" data-ng-if="userName">
    <a href class="dropdown-toggle clear" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-show="userName">
    </a>
    <!-- dropdown -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu>
        <li ng-hide="fb_id">
            <a ui-sref="app.changePassword">Change Password</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ui-sref="app.changeProfilePic">Change Profile Picture</a>
        </li>
        <li data-ng-show="userName">
            <a ui-sref="access.signout" data-ng-if="userName">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- / dropdown -->
</li>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.logIn = function (user) {
    $scope.myPromise = AuthService.login({
        'uid': user.email,
        'password': user.password,
    }).then(function (response) {
        $localStorage.userName = response.userName;
        $scope.userName = $localStorage.userName;
    }, function (error) {
        $scope.authError = true;
    });
};
```

Sign out controller:

```
$scope.userName = "";
delete $localStorage.userName;
$rootScope.userName = "";
```

Doesn't matter I use `ng-if` or `ng-show` it is still showing the logout button and the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below code.

```
<a ui-sref="access.signout" data-ng-if="userName != ''">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. This one actually fixed it. Actually setting `userName=null` didn't work for dropdown

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
<li data-ng-show="userName !== ''">
    <a ui-sref="access.signout">Logout</a>
</li>
```